# "TIBCO EMS TCPLink Reader " thread keep increasing

Tags: tibco, tibco-ems

We have one application which use Tibco EMS as message middleware, however we found that some threads which related with tibco keep increasing and now it is over 5000, and we need to restart our server after several days as we received thread threshold alert.

> "TIBCO EMS TCPLink Reader (Server-800893673)" #108119 daemon prio=5
> os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f04e239e000 nid=0x6da2 runnable
> [0x00007f0152baa000]    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE  at
> java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)     at
> java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)     at
> java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)   at
> java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)   at
> java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)    at
> java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
>
> - locked <0x000000073b113240> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)   at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387)    at
>   com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxLinkTcp._readWireMsg(TibjmsxLinkTcp.java:625)
>   at
>   com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxLinkTcp$LinkReader.work(TibjmsxLinkTcp.java:280)
>   at
>   com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxLinkTcp$LinkReader.run(TibjmsxLinkTcp.java:259)
>
> "TIBCO EMS Pinger for connection Server-800893673" #108118 daemon
> prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f01986fb800 nid=0x6da1 waiting on
> condition [0x00007f01530af000]    java.lang.Thread.State:
> TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)  at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)    at
> com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxLinkTcp$LocalPinger.run(TibjmsxLinkTcp.java:113)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Check if you closing all the connections after reading response from temporary queues. Also if you respond to temporary queues check if you set expiration for the message. You can use tool like tIbco admin or GEMS to see if there are too many temp queues created.

Comment: Is this a Java application using the TIBCO EMS JMS API ? If you see threads increasing you may need to check the application source code.

Comment: hi, EmmanueIM, we found the root cause is that we cache the connection without release, so have fixed it.